# numpy slicing select parts of array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a one dimensional array from which I would like to create a new array containing only parts of user wished sizes of the beginning, the middle, and the end of the former.

```
import numpy
a = range(10)
a
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```

I would like b to be equal to:

```
b
array([0, 1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 9])
```

Assuming that b is constructed of the concatenation of a[:3], a[5:6], and a[9].
I can of course use things such as np.concatenate, but is there a way to do that with slicing method, or anything else in one line?

Comment: Its really hard to understand what you're asking for.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to create an array of the indices you want to index your array with:

```
import numpy
a = numpy.arange(10)
i = numpy.array([0, 1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 9])  # An array containing the indices you want to extract
print a[i]  # Index the array based on the indices you selected
```

OUTPUT

```
[0 1 2 5 6 7 9]
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that the solution I'm seeking after should work even with arrays of 100's of elements.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

```
import numpy as np
a = range(10)
b = np.hstack([a[:3], a[5:6], a[9])
b
array([0, 1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 9])
```

but does slicing allow such a move?